# IIS HTTPS stopped working and can't bind self signed certificates to webiste in iis

Tags: visual-studio, iis, https, self-signed

My Win10 recently updated itself and seems like  IIS was updated as well (IIS 10.0.18362.1).

That caused problems with the my development website set in IIS:

1. All sites with https binding (with self-signed certificates) stopped working. When running the browser gives error: "This site can't be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

[image]

2. I am unable to assign any certificate to website. Get an error: "There was an error while performing this operation. A device attached to the system is not functioning. Exception from HRESULT 0x8007001F".

[image]

3. Starting any web application or website from VS IIS Express won't start it but gives same browser error: "This site can't be reached. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Any idea what happened to my system and how I can fix it?

Comment: What it says if you use another certificate?

Comment: same problem, same error message

Comment: reboot the machine and try to assign the certificate it will resolve both the error.